# Javascript Error in Child Window

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am trying to figure out why I am getting the error:

`"window.opener.document.aspnetForm.formType is null or not an object".`

I am passing a value from the parent window through a URL string to a popup window (this child window is a search form).
This value is an ID of a SharePoint form field (there is a reason I need to do it this way, the value indicates whether it is from the newform or editform).
I am declaring the variable formType from the value obtained in the url string using a function in the child window (geturlvalue()),

`var formType = geturlvalue(name);`

The variable "formType" is working in the child window fine, alerting it prior to the window opener shows the correct value from the parent window which is 
    `ctl00_m_g_004d943c_bb99_4fba_bee5_68862443b98d_ctl00_ctl04_ctl18_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_ctl00_TextField`

here is the opener in the child window:

```
window.opener.document.aspnetForm.formType.value = document.getElementById('Server').value;
```

the opener needs to populate an input field in the parent window from a value in the child window field with an ID of Server.

anyone have any idea as to why I am getting the error on formType? If I add `ctl00_m_g_004d943c_bb99_4fba_bee5_68862443b98d_ctl00_ctl04_ctl18_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_ctl00_TextField` to the opener in place of formType it works as it should and populates the parent input field:

window.opener.document.aspnetForm.ctl00_m_g_004d943c_bb99_4fba_bee5_68862443b98d_ctl00_ctl04_ctl18_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_ctl00_TextField.value = document.getElementById('Server').value;

Answer (score 2):

Looks like `formType` is the ID of element in the parent window, so in this case you need such code:

```
window.opener.document.getElementById(formType).value = document.getElementById('Server').value;
```

Comment: That was it! I forgot to remove aspnetForm when I tried this earlier. Simple oversights can make us crazy. Thanks for your help!

Comment: That's what we are here for. :)

Comment: I quess i was telling the same, but not quite as pregnant.

Comment: @Shadow well, it seems the term is a bit misleading =) Lets say its more telling without getting into more detail on this.

Answer (score 0):

Not really much detailed question, trying it anyways.

I'm really confused by your line :

```
window.opener.document.aspnetForm.formType.value = document.getElementById('Server').value;
```

What is it ?

Make sure that your form has a name="aspnetForm" (not an id), if you want to use:

```
window.opener.document.aspnetForm
```

And make sure your form elements have a name="formType" (not an id), if you want to use:

```
window.opener.document.aspnetForm.formType.value = ...
```

I wonder how you expect var formType being part of window.opener.document, but maybe you have defined all that stuff elsewhere in the code, so maybe you should post a bit more code, to allow others to understand what's going on in your program.

Comment: I just edited it for more clarity. FYI, this is being done in SharePoint 2007.